# '\\' characters are being treated as one character when using the length property in c#

Tags: c#, count, character

I am trying to get the length of a string that has `\\\` values.

> e.g. `"C:\\\Dir1\\\Dir2\\\Dir3\\\Dir4\\\flower.bmp"`

The length of the example is 38 characters.

When I use the length property the length is 33, basically it is treating `\\\` as one character.

I have tried using `StringInfo.LengthInTextElements` and various other ways to try and get this working but with no joy.

Comment: You should post more of your code, so we can also see why you are going this route.

Comment: \\ IS one character, its an escape character/sequence. Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut says you have a more fundamental problem, but have you tried wrapping it as a literal string?

```
string myString = @'C:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\Dir3\\Dir4\\flower.bmp'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the character `\` is used to escape characters in a string, `\\` actually represents the `\` character literally.

Try a verbatim string if you want `\\` to be treated as two characters:

`@"C:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\Dir3\\Dir4\\flower.bmp"`

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it is one char. if you want it to be 2 chars either use @ at the beginning or maybe \\ twice (haven't tried.. checking now)

Comment: You need to add backticks (\`) to properly display `\\\\ `.

Comment: 10x colin, I saw it didn't come well so I've just wrote "twice". :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `\\` in a C# string is known as an [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). Your string in code:

```
"C:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\Dir3\\Dir4\\flower.bmp"
```

becomes this string on disk and in memory when the program is loaded.

```
"C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Dir4\flower.bmp"
```

So, the length of your example *really is* 33 characters. The original string, while it may be 38 characters in code, only represents 33 real characters.

Answer (score 0):

33 is correct - `\\` is indeed only one character, namely `\`. It's only the debugger that shows it escaped (`\` has a special meaning for `\n` or `\r`, line feed and carriage return, respectively, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is an escape character to put special characters in your string like `\t` for a tab and `\n` for a newline. A double backslash `\\` will insert one backslash into the compiled string instead of your expected 2. The answer is to use the c# feature `@` in front of your string which prevent escaping or escaping all of your backslashes which would look like `"C:\\\\Dir1\\\\Dir2\\\\Dir3\\\\Dir4\\\\flower.bmp"`